# Battleship Shot Firing [Java]

Tags: java

The goal is to minimize the amount of shots I take at a battleship board that is randomly generated. My fireShot() method is supposed to determine if the point in my 2D array was already shot at, a miss, or a hit.

```
public boolean fireShot()
{

Random rand = new Random();

int i = rand.nextInt(10); //generate 2 random numbers for rows and columns
int j = rand.nextInt(10);
Point shot = new Point(i,j);

while (mapState[i][j] != empty){ 
        j = rand.nextInt(10);
        i = rand.nextInt(10);
        mapState[i][j] = shotAt;
}

boolean hit = battleShip.shoot(shot);

if(hit == false){
   mapState[i][j] = miss;
}

else if(hit == true){
   mapState[i][j] = hitInt;
   huntMode(i,j);
}

 return false;   
}
```

The battleShip.shoot method returns a boolean if the point hits a boat.

The problem is that the efficiency is the same and not skipping elements that have already been missed or hit.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @WasiAhmad it's not changing the efficiency at all. The program should skip all the elements that were already hit or missed but it doesn't seem to be doing that.

Comment: do you want to generate random number which is not generated before? what did you mean by efficiency? why the program should skip all the elements that were already hit or missed? you question is still not clear!

Comment: please briefly explain what are you expecting and what are you getting. don't give partial information about your need, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @WasiAhmad The program shows how many turns it took to complete, and the point of the method is to minimize the amount of turns to make the game end faster. After a point is determined hit or miss, it should be skipped because repeating the same determined element only makes it slower.

Comment: So, you mean you don't want to generate a random number which was not generated before?

Comment: The issue looks like he just forgot to update the `shot` variable in the loop after updating `i` and `j`, basically. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: @YonaAppletree Thanks for the advice but it looks like that didn't solve the efficiency problem :( I think the problem is that the while loop will just keep looping because the array's elements are all initialized as 0?

Comment: I agree with @YonaAppletree. however I really didn't understand what OP is doing inside that loop? what is `shotAt` and `empty` and what is `mapState`?

Comment: @WasiAhmad I initialized 4 variables to track how the elements have been treated. Miss = 1, Hit = 2, ShotAt = 3 and Empty is 0.

Comment: and mapState is a 2D array thats meant to represent the battleship board (10x10)

Comment: so you are actually trying to find a board position which is empty, right? and your code is taking long time to find such a position, is that correct? @SikiDamjanovic

Comment: @WasiAhmad Right now its just randomly shooting at the board and shooting at some elements more than once. What i'm trying to do is create a method that will not shoot at elements that have been shot before.

Comment: @SikiDamjanovic i have discussed an important aspect of your code in my answer, hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not efficient because it is trying to find unused points randomly, which will require more and more attempts once the map gets more and more filled.

Therefore you should try to avoid to get random numbers in the whole map but only in the subset of points that were not already used.

To do so you could create a `List` of not used `Points` and use `rand` to get an index in this `List`. The object at that index is going to be an unused point that is getting shot. Once you do that you remove that `Point` from the `List` so the next `rand` would still generate an index pointing to an unused point.

For example, you first generate the `List` of unused points:

```
int maxX = 10;
int maxY = 10;

// create the list with all the map positions: (0,0)(0,1)...(9,9) 
List<Point> pointsToTry = new ArrayList<Point>();
for (int iy = 0; iy < maxY; iy++) {
    for (int ix = 0; ix < maxX; ix++) {
        pointsToTry.add(new Point(ix, iy));
    }
}
```

Then at every shot you simply:

```
// get a random index of an unused point
int i = rand.nextInt(pointsToTry.size());
// remove that point from the list so it will not be picked again
Point shot = pointsToTry.remove(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you're storing the I and J values in two places: as `i` and `j` and also in the `shot` variable. In the while loop you assign new values to `i` and `j` but not to `shot`, so it's always set to the original value when you call `battleShip.shoot()`. I suggest not creating the `shot` `Point` until you call `battleShip.shoot()`. Also, I suggest using a `do {} while()` loop instead of `while` so you don't have to duplicate the random calls. You also don't need to check `hit == true` you can just do `if (hit) ... else ...` Something like this:

```
public boolean fireShot() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int i, j;

    do {
        j = rand.nextInt(10);
        i = rand.nextInt(10);
    } while (mapState[i][j] != empty);

    mapState[i][j] = shotAt;

    boolean hit = battleShip.shoot(new Point(i, j));

    if (hit) {
        mapState[i][j] = hitInt;
        huntMode(i, j);
    } else {
        mapState[i][j] = miss;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed my previous answer and now trying to address a problem that your code is suffering from.

```
int i = rand.nextInt(10); //generate 2 random numbers for rows and columns
int j = rand.nextInt(10);

while (mapState[i][j] != empty){ 
        j = rand.nextInt(10);
        i = rand.nextInt(10);
        mapState[i][j] = shotAt;
}
```

In the above code snippet, for example if `i = 4 and j = 6` and it was shot before, then you would enter the while loop since the condition is `mapState[i][j] != empty` where `empty = 0`. Then you again generate a pair of numbers and assign `shootAt` and then again check the condition of the while loop which is always going to be false because of the `mapState[i][j] = shotAt;` statement inside that loop. (you should encounter an infinite loop here)

The only time when you can return a value from your `fireShot()` method is: if for the random number pair `i, j` generated before entering the while loop, board state is empty (never shot before). Right? Hopefully you can understand the mistake now. That's why @YonaAppletree modified your code in the following way.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int i, j;

do {
    j = rand.nextInt(10);
    i = rand.nextInt(10);
} while (mapState[i][j] != empty);

mapState[i][j] = shotAt;
```

Now this do-while loop will find an empty cell from the board to shoot at: what you actually aimed to do. But the answer @LorisSecuro provided is more worthy and you should follow that.

Let me know if you think whatever i have said is incorrect.